# SQL Query Returns More Than 1 Row - Need 1 Row

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I currently have the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT
  con_Content,
  cot_Name,
  pag_Name
FROM 
  [Page]
  inner join [Content] on con_PageID = pag_ID
  inner join [ContentType] on cot_ID = con_TypeID
WHERE 
  pag_URL = 'tour'
```

that returns multiple rows like the screenshot below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GbHi.gif

i really need this query to return 1 row with the additional column names to be 'LeftColumn', 'RightColumn', 'MainContent' and the value of those columns to be the 'con_content' .

My SQL is not very good right now.

Comment: Look up the `pivot` keyword.  The msdn page (at the end of this comment) has good examples and can probably help you : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Donnie, it sounds like you want to do a pivot.  If this is for SQL Server 2005 or later:

```
with Page (con_Content, cot_Name, pag_Name)
as
(
    select '<p>this could be the left content</p>', 'LeftColumn', 'Tour'
    union
    select '<p>this could be the right content</p>', 'RightColumn', 'Tour'
    union
    select '<p>main content</p>', 'MainContent', 'Tour'
)
select pag_Name, LeftColumn, RightColumn, MainContent
from [Page]
pivot
(
    min(con_Content)
    for cot_Name in (LeftColumn, RightColumn, MainContent)
) as PivotTable
where pag_Name = 'Tour'
```

and if this is not SQL Server 2005+:

```
/* with cte defined as above */
select pag_Name, 
    max(case cot_Name when 'LeftColumn' then con_Content else '' end) LeftColumn,
    max(case cot_Name when 'RightColumn' then con_Content else '' end) RightColumn,
    max(case cot_Name when 'MainContent' then con_Content else '' end) MainContent
from [Page]
where pag_Name = 'Tour'
group by pag_Name
```

**Edit**

If there is no corresponding `cot_Name` value for a field in the pivot list, the query will still execute and return `null` for that field.

For example, try this:

```
with Page (con_Content, cot_Name, pag_Name)
as
(
    select '<p>this could be the left content</p>', 'LeftColumn', 'Tour'
    union
    select '<p>main content</p>', 'MainContent', 'Tour'
)
select pag_Name, LeftColumn, RightColumn, MainContent
from [Page]
pivot
(
    min(con_Content)
    for cot_Name in (LeftColumn, RightColumn, MainContent)
) as PivotTable
where pag_Name = 'Tour'
```

So in your case, you could include every value you are interested in, and just check for `null` to see whether the `pag_Name` has any content for that `cot_Name`:

```
/* using cte as defined above */
select pag_Name, LeftColumn, RightColumn, MainContent, MoreContent_1, MoreContent_2 /* etc. */
from [Page]
pivot
(
    min(con_Content)
    for cot_Name in (LeftColumn, RightColumn, MainContent, MoreContent_1, MoreContent_2)
) as PivotTable
where pag_Name = 'Tour'
```

Comment: almost there, my only issue is i will not know if the page contains LeftColumn, RightColumn, is there anyway to make the query more dynamic? Thanks again

Comment: @James, if there is no row for 'LeftColumn' or 'RightColumn', it would return NULL for that column in the pivoted output.  See my edit for an example.

Comment: i think it is very close. It may be me being dumb! i ran the top query and it works great however still includes the: 
    select '<p>this could be the left content</p>', 'LeftColumn', 'Tour'
    union
    select '<p>main content</p>', 'MainContent', 'Tour'

then i ran the second query and it doesnt work. excuse me if this is very frustrating for you. can you confirm the query to run

Comment: @James, the `select <p>this could be the left content</p>...` is a common table expression.  Think of it as a way to specify a temporary table to be used in the `select` statement that follows it without having to create an actual table.  You do not need to include that in the query you would run on your database.  I just did that so it could be easily copied/pasted and run without having to actually create the table.  And that also explains why the second query did not run as is - I did not include the cte.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that every page has a left, right & middle content you might make it simpler by adding a left, right and middle field to the page table. Otherwise, personally, I would handle the transformation in the application.

Comment: everypage potentially could have more or less. i want to make the application as flexible as possible.